# AtomicLongMap vs. ConcurrentHashMultiset

Tags: java, collections, guava

From the documentation of [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html):

> **Note**: If your values are always positive and less than 2^31, you may wish to use a Multiset such as ConcurrentHashMultiset instead. **Warning**: Unlike Multiset, entries whose values are zero are not automatically removed from the map. Instead they must be removed manually with removeAllZeros().

It states that you **may** wish to use a Multiset. My question is, what are the benefits of a Multiset over an AtomicLongMap? What considerations should I use when choosing a map containing only positive values? Is the only reason to use a Multiset, the fact that I don't need to call `removeAllZeros()` manually?

Comment: Short answer to the question about benefits of `Multiset`: API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) is conceptually different. First, it's a `Collection`, so it can be used as collection, while `AtomicLongMap` is not a collection (and not a map either). The multiset represents a set of possibly repeating elements and to perform math operations with their counts, you add or remove elements. The `AtomicLongMap` method names more consistent with `AtomicLong` class and explicitly assume that you are performing math operations on the values. Some operations can be unsupported by one implementation or another. For example, there are `addAndGet` and `getAndAdd` ops in `AtomicLongMap`, but `Multiset` has only `add` method which works like `getAndAdd`.

So while in many cases these classes are interchangeable, use `ConcurrentHashMultiset` if you think of your data as of collection of possibly repeating elements. Use `AtomicLongMap` if you think of your data as of mapping between the key and the `long` value.

Note that since Java-8, these classes can be easily replaced with standard JDK `ConcurrentHashMap<K, Long>`. For example, you may use `map.merge(key, 1L, Long::sum);` to increment the mapped value.